# What would be the number of possible (correct and incorrect) images on a cube puzzle?

Tags: combinatorics

Let’s assume that we have n cubes with each cube having a different image on each side (so 6 images for each cube with no two images the same inbetween cubes as well). Now let’s arrange these cubes into a matrix-like shape with r rows and c columns — so for example 3x4. How can we calculate the number of possible configurations assuming we can turn each cube around for a different side and that we can rearrange them? I understand that without turning (only rearranging), the answer is (r*c)!, however I’m not sure about the other option. Thanks!

Cubes in question - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN7Nl.jpg

Comment: Assuming all faces distinct and do not have rotational symmetry, pick which of the cubes occupies the top-left spot.  Pick which of the faces was visible.  Pick which orientation it is in.  Repeat the process for each other position.  This gives $(r\cdot c)!\cdot 6^{r\cdot c}\cdot 4^{r\cdot c}$.  Now, rotational symmetry of the entire board may come into play, so divide by $4$ if square board and by $2$ if non-square if you so wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JMoravitz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, there are $(r\cdot c)!$ different arrangements for the cubes. Then, once the slots have been chosen, there are 6 possibilities for each of the $r\cdot c$ cubes; that is, $6^{rc}$. So $(r\cdot c)!$ different arrangements and $6^{rc}$ different configurations for each arrangement make a total of...

Moreover, if you also consider the orientation of the image (4 possible orientations), instead of a 6 you, would need to use a 24 (that, is, $6\cdot 4$).